# Realm causes ANR error with no error message.

Tags: java, android, realm, breakpoints, android-anr-dialog

I've heard that Realm is as fast as to use in main thread. 
But sometimes, when I insert or update my data(even just a text!), it makes ANR error and nothing to do. 
I don't know why this is happened. because there is no error message either.

I've checked in debugging mode so that i found the system is executed until just

realm.executetransaction

and then, disappear breakpoint and nothing to do...
is there any person who has problem like me..?
Please help

Comment: include the source code

Comment: If your background thread transaction takes a long time, then opening a transaction on UI thread will block the UI thread. There is also possibility that someone in your code uses `realm.copyFromRealm()` even though they shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

In the realm docs it is recommended to use async transactions while writing to realm from the UI thread, as writing in transactions can sometimes blocking. This may cause ANR in the main thread. Please read further about async transactions here: [Realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#asynchronous-transactions).

Here is the sample example for async transaction from the docs:

```
RealmAsyncTask transaction = realm.executeTransactionAsync(new 
        Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
                User user = bgRealm.createObject(User.class);
                user.setName("John");
                user.setEmail("john@corporation.com");
            }
        }, null);
```